# In App purchase for iOS (Appcelerator)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I want to add in-app purchase functionality for iOS but I can't make it working.

I tried to use ti.storekit, but when I initialize it I get error that `addTransactionObserver` is undefined and this is crucial function on initialization.

Does anyone have luck with it?

My code:

```
var storekit = require('ti.storekit');
var transactionStateChanged = function(e) {
    alert(e)
}


function init() {
    storekit.receiptVerificationSandbox = Ti.App.deployType !== 'production';
    storekit.bundleVersion = '1.0.4';
    storekit.bundleIdentifier = 'pl.aplikacjanowa';
    storekit.addEventListener('transactionState', transactionStateChanged);
    storekit.addTransactionObserver();
}

init();
```

Error:

```
[INFO] :   [object TiStorekitModule] loaded
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 37;
[ERROR] :      line = 598;
[ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'storekit.addTransactionObserver()')";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///xyz"; //instead of xyz is path to file in which that function invoked
[ERROR] :      stack = "init@file:///xyz"; //instead of xyz is path to file in which that function invoked
[ERROR] :  }
```

Comment: have you read this? https://medium.com/all-titanium/monetising-your-ios-titanium-app-in-app-purchases-de35d55feb81#.svt4vj7fg

Comment: @RenePot: Yes, I read it. Trying to install module via gittio returns 'no distributable available', so I compiled module sources same as described in comments from your link.

Comment: But I get this addTransactionObserver undefined error.

Comment: please edit your question with details when the error occurs. It is hard to guess. Show your code, show the exact moment when the error happens. So full error stack (probably more than just 1 word)

Comment: @RenePot: I added code and error message. Do u have any idea?

Comment: have you downloaded the latest release? https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/releases/tag/ios-3.1.2

Comment: @RenePot: Hello, It seems that there was something wrong going during compilation from sources. I've downloaded it from link you provided, added to project and it works without any problems. Thank you for your help! Please add this as an answer so I can mark it and you can get reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you initially used outdated version of the module or incorrectly compiled it.

As you mention in your comment something *did* go wrong with compiling I'm assuming that is the issue. A good description how to implement the module is on [Medium](https://medium.com/all-titanium/monetising-your-ios-titanium-app-in-app-purchases-de35d55feb81#.svt4vj7fg), and releases are available for download from the [Appcelerator GitHub](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/releases/). Don't trust on Gitt.io from always having the latest.

Comment: But it is worth to mention that if we speak about installing (not configuring) Medium describes installation via Gitt.io, which is not possible, because it will return

`[INFO]  ti.storekit searching...
[ERROR] ti.storekit:commonjs no distributable available
[ERROR] ti.storekit:ios no distributable available`

Still good answer and step-by-step configuration tough.

Comment: Yes good point! I asked the author of the article to update it